# TypeError when invoking function from one class in another class

Tags: python

I have a class ("LogicalUnit") in which I am creating multiple functions and a class ("TestModule") in which I am using said functions. However, when I use a function from LogicalUnit in TestModule, I am getting a type error("unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'") from calling numpys dot function with two parameters. I am not sure why I would have a type error because I have not even declared the type of the parameters yet.

```
import numpy as np
class LogicalUnit():
    def __init__(self, table):
        self.X = table[:,0:3]
        self.Y = table[:,3:]
        self.w = np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0]).reshape(3,1)
        self.w = self.computeWeights(self.w,self.X,self.Y)
    def computeGradient(self,w, X, Y):
        pred = np.dot(self.X,self.w)
        pred = self.sigma(pred)
        gradient = np.dot(self.X.T, (pred-self.Y))
        return gradient/len(Y)
    def computeWeights(self,w,X,Y):
        for i in range(iterations):
            temp = lr * self.computeGradient(self.w,self.X,self.Y)
            w-=temp
```

---

```
import LogicalUnit as lu
import numpy as np
orData = np.array([...])
orUnit = lu.LogicalUnit(orData)
print("orUnit ", orUnit.getCurrentWeights())
```

Error:

```
runfile('C:/Python/TestModule.py', wdir='C:/Python')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-76-30a5f2d92222>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Python/TestModule.py', wdir='C:/Python')

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Neural\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Neural\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Python/TestModule.py", line 10, in <module>
    print("orUnit ", orUnit.getCurrentWeights())

  File "C:\Python\LogicalUnit.py", line 22, in getCurrentWeights
    return self.computeWeights(self.w,self.X,self.Y)

  File "C:\Python\LogicalUnit.py", line 19, in computeWeights
    temp = lr * self.computeGradient(self.w,self.X,self.Y)

  File "C:\Python\LogicalUnit.py", line 13, in computeGradient
    pred = np.dot(self.X,self.w)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: I suspect this errors is from "self.w = self.computeWeights(self.w,self.X,self.Y)" but I am not sure where else to put this line to change the weights to the computed weights.

Comment: In `__init__`, you're setting `self.w` to the result of `computeWeights()`, but that function doesn't return a value.

Comment: @cody Thank you. Where else can I place self.w to make the weights equal to w [by invoking the computeWeights() method] without causing this error?

Comment: always post the error message *including* the stack trace

Comment: @H.Khan I really can't make sense of what your code is trying to do, but the root cause of your error is that `computeWeights()` doesn't return a value, so `self.w` is being set to `None` in `__init__`. Then it causes `np.dot()` to fail when you pass it as the second argument to that function. So, what value should `computeWeights()` return?

Comment: @cody computeWeights computes the final weights of some data after n iterations [basically subtracting some value from "w" for n iterations].